# Preventing Rails from hanging while doing ssh?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ssh, fork

I have a compile button in my Rails app which does

```
get_pdf_cmd = ['ssh', '-i', '~/.ssh/id_rsa', '-o', 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no', 'root@compile', '/bin/bash', '--login', '/compile.sh', container['host'] ]

Rails.logger.info(get_pdf_cmd)

stdin, stdout_and_stderr, wait_thr = Open3.popen2e({}, get_pdf_cmd.join(" "))

Rails.logger.info stdout_and_stderr.gets(nil)
stdout_and_stderr.close
stdin.close
exit_code = wait_thr.value
```

and while this happens the entire Rails app hangs and is not responding at all.

**Question**

How can I prevent Rails from hanging while the SSH command is running?

Comment: Do it in ActiveJob?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as pointed out already in the comments, the best practice would be to use a background process to do the heavy lifting.

rails provides an abstraction-layer on top of the many job frameworks available for rails. read more on this topic in the guides http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html

if your rails application depends on the result of such an operation, you need to implement some kind of polling or use modern client communication style like ActionCable http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

`fork` is also possible, it's not recommended in a running rails application though.